# Java Application exploring on Max OS X

Tags: java, macos

I have created one desktop client in Java and created its app for Max OS X. I have set following property at start class and at every place where we are creating menus.

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().indexOf("MAC") != -1) {
            System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
            System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "My Project");
}
```

But on running at Mac OS X using app, show application in maximized state, as I click on maximized using (+) button then minimizing to tray, after that on clicking on app to explore always explore in small window at top right corner. How to resolve this problem.

I have three menus at menu bar and sometime it is showing only two, last one get disappeared, how to resolve it too.

Comment: Try changing the preferred/minimum size of the frame

Answer (score 0):

I have no real experience with creating Mac applications but I have created GUIs some..it seems to me that you don't have your properties resizing. Probably there is a setting for it but I honestly don't know what it might be...I just thought I would attempt to help since no one else has yet.